# Prevent text from breaking into new line when Printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print a web page, and this basically appears at the bottom near the footer.
The problem I am having is the text **Respectfully Submitted** and **Chief of FCD** breaks into a new line. And I want it to Respectfully Submitted and Chief of FCD each appear on their own lines.

**HTML**

```
<!-- printing class -->
   <span id="print-block-1" class="visible-print">
     <b>Respectfully Submitted:</b> <?php echo"$name"; ?>
   </span>
   <br><br>
   <hr>
   <div class="visible-print"  id="print-block-2">
     Chief of FCD
    </div>
   <br><br>
```

**CSS**

```
#print-block-1 {
    position:fixed !important;
    bottom: 120px !important;
    left: 570px !important;
    width:auto !important;
    font-size: 6pt !important;
}
#print-block-2 {
    position:fixed !important;
    bottom:80px !important;
    left:570px !important;
    width:auto !important;
    font-size: 6pt !important;
}
```

This is the screenshot

[image: A screenshot of Print Preview]

Comment: set the left of the first block to a smaller number and set the 'bottom' of both blocks to the same. You will have to do trail and error to figure out the left value for the first block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent word-wrapping in a phrase, replace the space with a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

Also, `!important` is a pretty blunt tool that should only be used on occasion. Read up on how **CSS specificity** works.